# Python: Return Text Position in a Image

Tags: python, image, coordinates, ocr, tesseract

I would like to localize a text Line from an image and output the position of the given text only for the Y coordinate in range of the Text Line. Is there a way to achieve this?
What I have already tried is to use the pytesseract function image_to_data() to output the position, but mostly this is just gibberish for me...
I thank you in advance for a source or a solution.

Thats how far i got..

```py
results=pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=pytesseract.Output.DICT)
imgDraw = ImageDraw.Draw(debugImg)
   for i in range(0, len(results["text"])):
       x = results["left"][i]
       y = results["top"][i]
       w = 10
       h = 10
       shape = ((0,y), (4, 4))
       imgDraw.rectangle(shape, fill=(0,0,255),outline="red")
   #Something to return
```

Comment: You can see a example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71983792/how-to-paint-a-rectangle-over-words/71984673#71984673